# Iot Core policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot-core

i'm trying to configure generic policy for all my IOT devices.
I would like that each IOT's device will be able to publish, consume and subscribe to his own topic only (include sub topics).
for example client "myclient" is able to consume, publish and subscribe to the following topics:
myclient/
myclient/a
myclient/a/b/c
etc..
what am i missing ?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
  {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "iot:Connect",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:11111111:client/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
  },
  {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "iot:Publish",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:11111111:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
  },
  {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "iot:Receive",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:11111111:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
  },
  {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
   "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:11111111:topicfilter/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
  }
 ]
 }
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: failed to login with this policy, when i updated the policy to be with full permission i'm able to login and sends/consumes messages :

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 2):

From your policy, it seems like you’re on the right track. You’ve set up permissions for your IoT devices to connect, publish, receive, and subscribe to their own topics. However, you might be missing the wildcard at the end of the **Resource** ARN for the `iot:Publish` and `iot:Receive` actions.

Here’s an example of a policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:11111111:client/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:11111111:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:11111111:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:11111111:topicfilter/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This policy should now correctly restrict each IoT device to only its own topics and subtopics for publishing, receiving, and subscribing. Try to review and test this policy in your environment to ensure it works as expected.

For more information on IoT policies, you may want to check out some resources on:

- [Configuring policy settings on IoT devices1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/commercialization/iot-ent-configure-policy-settings)
- [Creating a policy set in IoT Security2](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/iot/iot-security-admin/recommend-security-policies/create-a-policy-set-in-iot-security)
- [Configuring access control in Device Update
  for IoT Hub3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/configure-access-control-device-update?tabs=portal)

These resources might provide additional insights for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, not sure that i understand what did you mean, in my question i already added * at the end of each resource

Comment: also, do i need to configure a shadow or something else in the Thing?

Comment: @code123 MQTT and AWS IoT Core policies have different wildcard characters. This document should give you some more information: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html

Comment: @code123 unless you want to use the shadow feature, you don't have to configure the topic for it.